# Android Studio can't find support package symbols anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, adt

I've updated Android Studio to 0.8 and 0.8.2 and all has been good. **But**, today I booted the thing up and suddenly everything broke down. Somehow, it can't seem to load my support packages anymore (see screenshot). I've updated the complete SDK. I've installed the new API 20 ADT and all corresponding packages. There are no updates as of this writing for me to install. This problem seems to occur for me even on newly created projects.

[image]

The things I did to try and resolve this issue;

- Invalidating caches using the menu option.
- Reinstalling Android Studio (including the SDK)

  - Installing and older version of the SDK (e.g. installing Android Studio *0.6.whatever* and only installing API 19.
- Removing **EVERYTHING** Android Studio related like so;

> rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
>
> rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
>
> rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
>
> rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
>
> rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
>
> rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*

- Deleting all *.iml files and the .idea folder.
- Creating a local.properties file pointing to the (already known to Android Studio) android SDK.
- Rebuilding and/or cleaning didn't help
- Gradle Sync to Project and Gradle Synchronise both didn't do anything

And this; to no avail. Do you guys have any idea what I can do to get this show on the road again?

**PS**. For the record, I'm running OSX 10.9.4 and I've got JDK 1.8 U11 installed.

**PPS**. And no, using JDK 6 or 7 didn't make ANY difference whatsoever.

**EDIT** - forgot to mention; the source compiles and runs fine. Gradle doesn't give any errors either.

Comment: It might be a stupid suggestion, but have you tried to rebuild the project? Had something similar to this a few months back. That worked for me.

Comment: That's not a stupid suggestion at all, but yeah, I've tried that. Both cleaning and rebuilding didn't do a thing.

Comment: Is Gradle still running?

Comment: Gradle finishes fine. I can even compile and run the project!

Comment: Can you show us your build.gradle file for your main application module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after removing Android Studio again today and removing all of the following files, version 0.8.6 started behaving like normal again. It's also able to find my support package again.

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.studio.plist
~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
```

**n.b.**, I've tried removing these folders *before*. I've done so *multiple* times by now, but today Android Studio decided to work again. **I therefore suspect that something else was the culprit.**

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few combos: reinstall sdk, reinstall Android Studio, restart, clean, etc.

I ended up updating *build.gradle* like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 20        
    }

    compileOptions {
         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

It solved the issue. Unfortunately it took 5 hours to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that your problem wasn't akin to mine. I've changed my Gradle to incorporate your changes but it didn't help. I'm starting to think it's just something simple like android studio not being able to find my support package or something similar. Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

I think that you must change your project build target (an android version superior or equal to 15). In eclipse, you can do that by right clicking on your project>Properties>Android and then choose the project build target. I think that in Android Studio there is a similar option.

Comment: This **shouldn't** be the solution. I should *always* be able to build apps for Android versions lower than 15. And just to be sure, I've tried it; didn't work.

Comment: Choosing an android version superior to 15 as a build target doesn't mean that your application won't work for versions lower than 15. In fact, it's in your Manifest file that you indicate android versions that support your applicaton. Anyway, sorry that my response didn't help.